# JSON dict saving keys as string not int

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have saved a dictionary as json to re-use later across a number of areas.

The dictionary structure is:

```
dict = {
    1: 'Name',
    2: 'Name2',
    3: 'Name3'
}
```

I have saved it as so:

```
with open('fpath', 'w') as out :
    json.dump(dict, out)
```

When I am reading it back in, though, it reads the dictionary keys as strings, not ints, as follows:

```
with open('fpath', 'r') as inf :
    dict = json.load(inf)

print (dict)

dict = {
    '1': 'Name',
    '2': 'Name2',
    '3': 'Name3'
}
```

This makes it so I can't use it as needed, for example to map it to a pandas dataframe column.

How do I save the dictionary so that the keys are saved and read back in as ints, not strings?

Comment: you can't with json. Use python dict repr + ast.literal_eval

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you -- hadn't seen that question. Will refer to that!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to post-process the dict with the following line:

```
dict = {int(k):v for k,v in dict.items()}
```